# В программе по переводу из двоичной системы счисления в десятичную есть баг

Tags: java, массивы

прошу помочь и разобраться, всегда выводится число 50 либо 49

```
public long Convertin(int numberSystem , int number, int numberSystemAfter) {
    char[] mas = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
    char[] rezultmas = new char[0];
    long rezult = 0;
    if (numberSystem == 2 && numberSystemAfter == 10) {
        for (int i = mas.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char rezz = mas[i];
            rezultmas = String.valueOf(rezz).toCharArray();
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < rezultmas.length; a++) {
            rezult += (long) (rezultmas[a] * Math.pow(2, a));
        }

    }
    return rezult;
}
```

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать в первом цикле? В этой строчке вас ничего не смущает? `rezultmas = String.valueOf(rezz).toCharArray();`

Comment: программа по переводу чисел из двоичной системы счисления в десятичную должна принимать один аргумент (двоичное число) и возвращать один аргумент (десятичное число). зачем вам 3 аргумента на входе???